# the difference between "one Executor per Core vs one Executor with multiple Core"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

we know that each task is performed in one core at the time.
lets say we have cluster of node with this configuration :

10 node.
16 core per node.
64 gb Ram per node.

my question is what is the difference between **to have 1 executor with 16 core and  16 executor with 1 CORE ???**

i mean :[image]
VS
[image]

i get inspired from this source:
https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html?fbclid=IwAR3xiFLBXBkwX2SrcJFZU0tfHU7Gssp-NJstfLDSRSRZzJgK6ybvJjSVcpY

Thank in advance

Comment: Awesome question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to add to @dassum 's answer. There are a few more things to consider.

**"1 executor with 16 cores" case:**

If one of the tasks on these cores runs OOM or crashes in a bad way, up to 16 tasks (and their ancestors) need to be re-processed (vs just 1).

**"16 executors with 1 core each" case:**

In-memory data caching (`persist()`) is done per executor. So for a set total amount of RAM available, it means that only up to 1/16 of this memory can be given to each individual executor and that a large partition can potentially fail to be cached in memory, negatively affecting processing speed. Also, it is much more likely that one of the executors will run OOM because 
there is an overhead associated with running each of JVM instances so even a smaller portion of this 1/16 of potentially available RAM per executor can be used.
Also the executors normally don't share memory among themselves. So if one executor is not using as much memory as another one, the memory can't be given to the executor with higher memory needs. I.e. memory allocation is less efficient. That's unless spark.memory.offHeap.enabled is set to true (it is set to `false` by default).

Answer (score 9):

dassum's answer is absolutely correct, but to dig deeper into this:

- Tasks have lower overhead than running whole executor
- Data exchange is faster within the same process than between different processes
- Broadcasts (e.g. when you join a very small DataFrame to a huge multi-paritioned one) send copies of data to each of the executors, so the more executors, the more copies of this data have to be done

So by running 16 executors with one core each, you may see a performance drop when compared to 1 executor with 16 cores.

However!

- JVM doesn't work well with > 200GB of memory - Cloudera documentation recommendeds 64GB as a memory limit for single executor to limit garbage collection issues
- as mentioned in the article you linked, HDFS pretty much hits a throughput limit on 5 cores, so if you are running your cluster with YARN, that's the sensible limit

The cluster configuration matters in this case very much. On top of that partitioning of your data is another crucial factor. In the end if you have fewer partitions than available threads you won't be utilizing all of your cluster since each partition can be processed in only one thread. Another interesting case is when you have one more partition than number of cores - which is going to double your processing time assuming roughly equal size of partitions.

Answer (score 8):

1 executor with 16 core means you will have 1 JVM which can run maximum of 16 tasks

16 executor with 1 CORE  means you will have 16 JVM and each JVM can run one task.

Comment: so, in both cases, you'll have 16 concurrent tasks? but depending on the case you'll have different problems (1 executor configuration has its own problems, and 16 executors configuration has its own problems). Am I correct?